# Alternatives to Kotlin Coroutine in Swift

Tags: swift, kotlin, async-await, kotlin-coroutines

I would like to know what is the alternative of wait all tasks to finish before executing the next functions in Swift.

I tried the async/await functions of Swift, but the functions just run in the background instead of waiting until the tasks finish.

```
func checkData(firstName: String) async {
  Task(priority: .high) {
    await compareFirstName(firstName: firstName)
  }
  
  Task(priority: .low) {
    await uploadFirstName(firstName: firstName)
  }
}
```

I want the compareFirstName() to finish first, but the uploadFirstName() always finish before the compareFirstName().

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Swift uses a model of [structured concurrency](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Concurrency.html#ID642) for this. You can either manually create and use `TaskGroup`s, or you can use [`async let`](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Concurrency.html#ID641) to automatically have them generated for you.

Comment: Try sticking everything in the Task block, async has been deprecated.

Comment: Hi Alexander and Cora, i tried based on your advices, but the second function in my code still execute before the first one. Why? Please check my edited code.

Comment: You could use a serial DispatchQueue

Comment: @birkoof - No, you definitely don’t want to unnecessarily introduce a GCD serial queue in the middle of an `async`-`await` codebase.

Comment: Ive been testing everyone advise, but still it did not work as usual like when i did in kotlin

Answer (score 2):

> I tried the async/await functions of Swift, but the functions just run in the background instead of waiting until the tasks finish.

Because you wrote your code wrong. Put the `await`s into *one* task:

```
func checkData(firstName: String) async {
  Task {
    await compareFirstName(firstName: firstName)
    await uploadFirstName(firstName: firstName)
  }
}
```

Moreover, if `checkData` *is* `async`, you don't need the Task:

```
func checkData(firstName: String) async {
  await compareFirstName(firstName: firstName)
  await uploadFirstName(firstName: firstName)
}
```

If it is crucial that they run on different priorities, you can do various things such as nesting tasks.

Comment: Good answer! +1. The second is likely the appropriate approach. In this case, the “priorities” were undoubtedly a well-intentioned (but misguided) way of the OP to try to indicate relative priorities of two concurrent tasks. I’d advise against your first approach, as the `async` qualifier is declaring an informal contract, leading the caller to assume that it can `await` the asynchronous task, when, in fact, this first rendition will not. (In fact, if the OP employed this “throw in an unnecessary `Task { ... }`” pattern within `compareFirstName`, then even your second approach won't work!)

Comment: Ive been testing everyone advise, but still it did not work as usual like when i did in kotlin